# SharePoint 2007 : Document (.mht file) open by MS Word by default

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint, internet-explorer-8, ms-word

In SharePoint 2007 Document Library, when user click on the item (uploaded .mht file), it should open the mht file via Internet Explorer (IE).

It working fine in most of the machine except a few was not open directly via IE, when user click on the item, it is automatically by Microsoft Word instead of IE.

Any idea how can this be solve? could this happened due to the IE (version 7 & 8) settings?
Perhaps the site is not added as trusted site or activeX.

Please help. Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Anyone who know IE setting can solve my issue? please help

Answer (score 1):

It seems that user's default programs are changed. 
Look what is set in?

```
IE -> Internet Options -> Tools -> Html Editing
```

In the same menu html openers can be changed. Look for them too.
May be that users changed html opener and/or editors.

look this link for different way of going to same menu.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/250815

File Associations can be changed following way too.
default programs-> Set Associations
[image: File Associations]
https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-51fweCuqsxQ/Tq5iUfPKYyI/AAAAAAAAADE/8EpfyjO3LBc/w1640-h423-k/1.PNG

Open with can be used to set default program too.
[image: Open With Associations]
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Jws9VChWpPw/Tq5iUnucRWI/AAAAAAAAADA/Hp956T4nSps/w500-h233-k/2.png

Comment: thank you for your reply. however the solution still not able to solve my probblem

Answer (score 1):

Open **IE > Internet Options > Select "Programs" Tabs > Change "HTML Editor" dropdown** as your requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For the machine when open mht file in IE (Normal situation), after I changed the HTML editor to MS Word, it is still open via IE. In other word, I not able to simulate the situation where it is automatically open in MS Word.

Comment: Also one more thing, if you want to open this file from word you can use DOCICON.xml file for Default Open Application.

Comment: sure, I'm talking about the default setting, is there any other possible setting in IE which cause the document open with MS Word instead of IE?